# Как программа загружается в стек на aarch64?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, arm

До сих пор любил С, начал писать на ассемблере. Удобно, что телефон всегда с собой, поэтому архитектура aarch64. ArchLinux на Termux'е (proot, кажется). И вот запускаю условную программу и хочу считать её аргументы из стека (aka argv[]). Начало радужное: по адресу верхушки стека (sp) располагается количество аргументов (argc), со смещением на один байт — имя файла. А где искать имена аргументов? Непонятно.

Пример: программа main.
Запускаю: `./main arg1 arg2`
Бегаю по стеку на ± 1024 бит, вывожу строку через системный вызов write linux — кракозябры :(. Никакой зацепки. На статье про Nasm прочёл, что linux при запуске приложения сохраняет в стек подряд указатели на аргументы. Ан нет, не выходит. Можно, конечно, вывод gcc дизассемблировать, но как-то некруто и "магически". Есть доки на этот счёт? Куда искать, как искать? Что смотреть? Какие-нибудь ссылки на соглашения о вызове программ на Линуксе или на arm... Или всё настолько платформозависимо, что termux эмулирует по-своему? Может кто-то ответить или прикрепить ссылочки?

Буду признателен.

Comment: Аргументы функции (и main тоже) в aarch64 [передаются в регистрах](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_(A64)), целые в X0, ... X7 real в D0, ... D7.   Для main  в X0 будет argc, в X1 argv (адрес вектора указателей на строки аргументов) в X2  адрес аналогичного вектора на строки environment. Про передачу аргументов в стеке вы ошиблись, видимо по адресу, который смотрите остатки локальной памяти какой-то функции, отработавшей перед вызовом main

Comment: `"Куда искать, как искать? Что смотреть?"` -- как всегда в гугле. Набираете `aarch64 calling convention` и быстро находите что-то вроде   https://student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs452/docs/rpi4b/aapcs64.pdf  / Раньше (еще 2 года назад) была куча материалов в arm developer, но сейчас они доступны только через tor или vpn

Comment: @avp не использую Си — голый ассемблер. Метка _start. X0 пуст, а количество аргументов передаётся, как выяснилось, именно в стек — SP. А где искать аргументы — всё ещё неясно...

Comment: @avp вопрос скорее про то, куда Linux пихает аргументы, когда запускает приложение. Чуйка подсказывает, что в стек

Comment: А вот где найти?.. Загадка.

Comment: Я бы дизассемблировал (objdump-ом) и посмотрел, что делает код по адресу _start (это наверное какой-нибудь crt0.c). По идее он должен где-то дальше вызвать main тем способом, который я вам описал (по крайней мере я его так вызываю из своего стартового кода в bare metal и откомпилированный gcc main прекрасно работает). / Другой вариант -- взять сорсы линукса и посмотреть на реализацию execv

Comment: У Вас, @avp, стойкая привязка к Си. Нужен уровень ещё ниже. Не имею большого опыта с objdump. Вызвал с опцией -d — никаким main'ом там и не пахнет. Ровно то, что делал: секция _start, системный вызов 93. Ничего боле. Грустно. Буду искать.

Comment: Посмотрите описания [вот тут](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa?tab=readme-ov-file), хотя я не уверен, что существует уровень ниже сишного. Почти все пишут на нем, только первую сотню-другую инструкций, отрабатывающих по снятию ресета с ядра на асме (и естественно, функции из нескольких инструкций для доступа к системым регистрам (ну, пожалуй еще сохранение контекста при прерываниях и longjmp/setjmp))

Comment: @avp Как Пастернак сказал: Во всём мне хочется дойти \\ До самой сути. \\ В работе, в поисках пути, \\ В сердечной смуте.   Любопытно ж, как оно всё работает на уровне ассемблера! Подумываю о небольшом компилируемом языке, потому и нужен максимально низкоуровневый код. Писать фронтенд под gcc или LLVM — не вариант: уж больно громоздкие проекты. За ссылку спасибо, изучу.

Comment: Успехов. Можете продолжить [тут](https://www.arm.com/architecture/learn-the-architecture/a-profile) (у меня доступно через tor)

Comment: Стоило бы начать с того, что традиционной точке входа `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`, даже если аргументы передаются через стек, а не через регистры, то передается только один указатель на заканчивающийся нулем массив из указателей на С-style строки с аргументами. Массив и сами строки в любом случае лежат где-то в другом месте.

Comment: @user7860670 повторюсь: ассемблер, не С. Требуется мыслить не функциями, а адресами в памяти. В регистрах нет нужного.